# ASP.NET Gridview column with button CommandArgument Error, ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, gridview

I have added a button column in ASP.NET Gridview like so,

```
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="btnBlacklist" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Pass"
                     Text="PASS" CommandArgument ='<%# Eval("ACCOUNT_ID")%>'/>s
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

On the code behind, added the trigger event like so,

```
Protected Sub gTransReport_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)

    If e.CommandName = "Pass" Then
        Dim accountId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)

        DbConn = New OleDbConnection()
        Try
            dbdll.ConnectDB(connString, DbConn)
            If DbConn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                DbConn.Open()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ClassMC.putToErrorLog("[" & Session("USER").ToString().Trim & "] " & ex.Message & ex.StackTrace)
            Session("ERRORDESC") = ex.Message & " " & ex.StackTrace
            Page.Response.Redirect("ZapError.aspx")
        End Try
        Try
            Using dbCommand As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE AML_INDIVIDUAL_PERCENTAGE SET SECOND_NAME = 'PASS' WHERE ACCOUNT_ID = '@accountID'", DbConn)

                dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountID", accountId)
                dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            ClassMC.putToErrorLog("[" & Session("USER").ToString().Trim & "] " & ex.Message & ex.StackTrace)
            Session("ERRORDESC") = ex.Message & " " & ex.StackTrace
            Page.Response.Redirect("ZapError.aspx")
        Finally
            DbConn.Close()
        End Try
        lblBlacklist.Text = "User passed!!"
    End If
End Sub
```

The GridView with the report displays fine, but when i click the PASS button, `ORA-01722: invalid number` error is thrown. My database schema, `ACCOUNT_ID` is a `NUMBER`. i have debugged my code and and dont know why its throwing this error, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't wrap parameter in apostrophes like here:

```
 WHERE ACCOUNT_ID = '@accountID'
```

instead:

```
 WHERE ACCOUNT_ID = @accountID
```

otherwise the string `@accountID` is used as value for the accountID which is not a number.

---

**Update**: afaik in oracle it is

```
 WHERE ACCOUNT_ID = :accountID
```

Comment: when i remove the apostrophes, it throws `ora-00936: missing expression` but when i wrap with the apostrophes its ok.

Comment: @Lawrence: try the colon, i'm not so familiar with oracle but i guess it's `:` instead of `@`.

Comment: `@Tim Schmelter` Fixed

Comment: _Fixed_ means that it works with `:` or that you have fixed it in another way?